# If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $A^k = I$, then $A = \lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and suppose there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A^k = I$. Prove that if $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$, then $A = \lambda I$.

All I found out is the following:

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ be the only eigenvalue of $A$, and let $v\in V$ be a corresponding eigenvector. It follows
$$
A^kv = \lambda^kv = v \Leftrightarrow \lambda^k = 1\Leftrightarrow |\lambda| = 1
$$

But from here, I am stuck, can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to somehow show that $A$ is diagonlizable.  One way to so is to note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^k - 1$, and can be therefore written as the product of distinct linear factors.

If we want to avoid general statements about minimal polynomials (i.e. if you don't know what a minimal polynomial is), we have the following approach: note that
$$
A^k - I = 0
$$
we can factor the above into the product
$$
(A - \omega_1 I)(A - \omega_2 I) \cdots (A - \omega_k I) = 0
$$
where each $\omega_i$ is a distinct root of the polynomial $x^k - 1$.

Now, note that $A$ has exactly $1$ eigenvalue, so for all but one value $\omega_i$, the matrix $A - \omega_i I$ is invertible.

Comment: Your $n=k\ne n$ above.

Comment: @A.G. strangely phrased but point taken. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to using the minimal polynomial is the jordanization of $A$.

If $A^k=I$ then the same is true for the Jordan normal form of $A$, i.e. $J^k=I$, and, therefore, even for each separate Jordan block $(\lambda I+N)^k=I$, where $N$ is the canonical nilpotent matrix with all zeros except the first subdiagonal with ones. Now since
$$
(\lambda I+N)^k=\lambda^kI+{k\choose 1}\lambda^{k-1}N+{k\choose 2}\lambda^{k-2}N^2\ldots=I
$$
it is clear that the Jordan block must be scalar, otherwise we always get nonzero off-diagonal elements in the LHS, which contradicts the equality. Thus, the Jordan form must be diagonal.